# How to analyse a file .py using ast

Tags: python, python-3.x, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm trying to create a program in Python 3.7 that creates a pdf file with some information that is kept in a file.py. For example, pdf should looks like:

```
Imported libraries are:
     -task1: line 1
     -task2: line 2
The comments on code are:
     -new way: line 7
     -we exit infinite loop: line 9
```

My question is how to use ast library (or another way) to analyse a file with extension .py in order to search for the imports that i did (in that file.py) and in what line they are in order to write it in the pdf. Also i want to search for the comments that i put and also the line where they are.

Comment: You might want to read a tutorial about using `ast`, but you could try the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html). BTW welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour] and [ask] for advice.

Comment: Thank you for documentation, i'm new at phyton and i don't know how the Abstract syntax tree works.